# How to play Imperialism 2 with multiplayer manual battles?

Tags: imperialism-2

**Background:**
My big brother wants to play a very limited amount of games, because he's an old fart.

He said he'd play Imperialism II with me if the battles were manual (because I took his capital once with a very small force, which is admittedly unfair, on manual-battle-mode that would've been impossible).

**Is there a way to get manual battles enabled in multiplayer, in Imperialism II?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user85190! I'm sorry to say that so far, there is no way to play manual multiplayer in Imperialism II. I really wish they did, but sadly there is no information mentioning this type of game mode on a number of sources I searched, ranging from the official Imperialism page to various Reddit and Wikipedia articles on the game.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also my experience after searching high and low :(